# Help with putting Hair braid into a different Blend file

Tags: hair

I made a braid using the new curves guides in 3.5 but whenever I try to append or copy the braid into another file it just shows as straight hair without all the modifiers, regardless if I've applied them.

It took a lot of tweaking to get the braid to look right so this is getting annoying I can't just simply add it to the file that my character is in

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by the subdivision in curves EEVEE settings being too low when I pasted it into a new file